# Sorting items by category in Django

Tags: django

I am a newcomer to Django and I want to know how can I categorize objects I've created in admin panel and sort them by those categories when rendered.
This is what I tried but I don't know if it's how it works:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('popular', ('Popular Posts')),
        ('new', ('New Posts')),
        ('suggestions', ('Music Suggestions')),
    )
    category = models.CharField('Post Category', max_length=40, choices=CATEGORY, default='popular')
    title = models.CharField('Title of the post',max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField('Page content', max_length=500)
    posted = models.DateTimeField('last updated')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the ordering field in the Meta class

```
class Post(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('popular', ('Popular Posts')),
        ('new', ('New Posts')),
        ('suggestions', ('Music Suggestions')),
    )
    category = models.CharField('Post Category', max_length=40, choices=CATEGORY, default='popular')
    title = models.CharField('Title of the post',max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField('Page content', max_length=500)
    posted = models.DateTimeField('last updated')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("category",)
```

or you can also use list filters in the model admin